# GridView data which should span 4 columns all displayed under the first

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to populate a `GridView` with data from a `DataTable`. The DataTable has 4 columns, however, once I bind the data to the GridView, it crams the four entries into the first column.

Here is what I have:

C#:
Creating DataTable and populating with data.

```
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    DataColumn d = new DataColumn(i.ToString());
                    dt.Columns.Add(d);
                }
                if (Session["dt"] == null)
                {
                    Session["dt"] = dt;
                }

                dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
                dt.Rows.Add(new Object[4] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
                Session["dt"] = dt;
        }
```

Grabbing DataTable from Session and binding to GridView.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

ASP.NET

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="0" HeaderText="0" SortExpression="0" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="1" HeaderText="1" SortExpression="1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="2" HeaderText="2" SortExpression="2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="3" HeaderText="3" SortExpression="3" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The column names in the GridView match those of the DataTable, and when I check the DataTable after adding a row to it, they are all underneath their correct columns in there.

EDIT
Screenshot of output:
[image: Output]

Comment: I tried to re-create the example and it shows 4 columns as expected, could you add a screenshot in your question to see how is it showing at your end?

Comment: @RashidAli Just added it in

Comment: looks like its a CSS issue, Grid is correctly creating 4 columns in header as well as row

Comment: @RashidAli You were right, I completely removed my own style sheet I had added and it fixed the issue! Knew it would be something stupidly simple, thank you.